# sql group by with double conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the amount of distinct parent_ids that fill in one of the conditions below , grouped by day:
parent_ids that have both status = pending & processing
OR
parent_ids who have both status = canceled and processing.

I ve tried something similar to :

```
SELECT count(parent_id) as pencan, created_at, DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%Y') AS year_key, DATE_FORMAT(a.created_at, '%m-%d') as day_key
FROM sales_flat_order_status_history 
where created_at BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-30 23:59:59'
GROUP BY created_at ,parent_id
HAVING SUM(status = 'processing')
AND SUM(status IN ('pending', 'cancelling'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to fix the `group by`:

```
SELECT DATE(created_at), count(parent_id) as pencan
FROM sales_flat_order_status_history 
where created_at >= '2010-01-01' AND
      created_at < '2013-05-01'
GROUP BY DATE(created_at) , parent_id
HAVING SUM(status = 'processing') AND
       SUM(status IN ('pending', 'cancelling'))
```